# How to fix LG Tribute stuck at 0% on "Firmware Update"?

Tags: updates, device-firmware

My parents bought me an LG Tribute from the store. Suddenly, it is stuck on a screen saying "Firmware update", and is stuck at 0%.

I have seen people saying to remove the battery, but if I do that, I cannot turn the phone back on, because my power button has stopped working over a week ago. Does anyone know how to fix this?